# Best tool for image segmentation

Tags: image

Does anybody knows which are the best tools for image segmentation?
I'm starting to do a project that evolves in a specific GUI to recognize some parts of the image such as a button, or a text box for example.

Can anybody tell me which sould be the easiest and the most efficient tool for this kind of issues?

Thank You.

Comment: Your question is a poor fit for Stack Overflow which aims to provide insights and assistance to coding questions and doesn't provide recommendations of tools, libraries and off-site resources.

Answer (score 5):

Though your question may not be well posed, there are several tool kits for image processing.

One option is [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/). This computer vision library can perform a wide range of operations from simple image processing to object recognition for robotics.  Here is one quick [image segmentation example](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html), straight from the documentation.

This library is powerful, but it may not suit your application.  Please consider asking a more specific, technical question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
My point is for example a have a certain interface that have buttons and textboxes. And i need to recognize those buttons and do the image segmentation process. I searched many tools like OpenCV, CVIPtools, VLFeat and MATLAB computer Vision toolbox. 
And i was wondering wich one was the best one for this specific work.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have only directly used OpenCV and MATLAB.  The right choice depends on several variables, including preferred programming language and deployment platform.  What language are you working in?  Are you going to run the app on an embedded device or a server? Several of the toolboxes within MATLAB are written on top of the OpenCV library.

Comment: the prefered language would be or python or java. The app will be running in a virtual machine.

Comment: Just jump in and get started; return here when you have specific quetions! Install OpenCV with pyhton bindings and play around with the library to suit your needs: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/opencv-tutorials-resources-guides/  Good luck and have fun learning :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Mepix!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few toolboxes for pattern recognition in images> 
in matlab you can find: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46392-pattern-recognition-toolbox
It is called PRTools> http://prtools.org/

and this is for more statistical purposes rather than segmentation> 
http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/cmp/software/stprtool/dwstprtool.html

If you deal with neuroimages, you can then take a look on> 
Pattern Recognition for Neuroimaging Toolbox (PRoNTo)